# TIKTOK API - Requesting more responses from hashtag API class

Tags: pandas, api, python-requests, tiktok

I am running the following code to retrieve account info by hashtag from the unofficial TikTok Api.

API Repository - https://github.com/davidteather/TikTok-Api

Class Definition - https://dteather.com/TikTok-Api/docs/TikTokApi/tiktok.html#TikTokApi.hashtag

However it seems the maximum number of responses I can get on any hashtag is 500 or so.

Is there a way I can request more? Say...10K lines of account info?

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi
import pandas as pd

hashtag = "ugc"
count = 50000

with TikTokApi() as api:
    tag = api.hashtag(name=hashtag)
    print(tag.info())

    lst = []
    for video in tag.videos(count=count):
        lst.append(video.author.as_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```

The above code for hashtag "ugc" produces only 482 results. Whereas I know there is significantly more results available from TikTok.

Answer (score 0):

It’s ratelimit, TikTok will block you after a certain amount of requests.

Comment: Ok thank you. Do you know of any way to get around that?

Answer (score 0):

Add proxy support like this:

```
proxies = open('proxies.txt', 'r').read().splitlines()
            proxy = random.choice(proxies)
            proxies = {'http': f'http://{proxy}', 'https': f'https://{proxy}'}
```

Could be more precise but it's a way to rotate them